# Google Chrome displaying Google WebFont wrong

Tags: css, google-chrome

I hope someone may help me figure this out,

the problem is with a Google WebFont being displayed poorly in Google Chrome (ironic isn't it). Here is a picture of the problem:

[image]

And here the link to the WIP Site: http://klok-bremen.de/noire/index.html

I underlined all the problematic letters with red. The letters with problems are those with ascenders. You can see how the O, Q, G, S and C are not positioned how they should be, but perhaps one or two pixels too high.

Now this problem only occurs in Google Chrome. However the Chrome on my Macbook is displaying the Font right. It is just my Windows PC which displays the Font on Chrome like this.

If this is a problem with my computer, it isn't that important, however it would still be nice to know what's causing it.

CSS in question:

```
.menu-list li {
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 1em;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: An image isn't going to help much. We'd need to see the HTML / CSS as to how you implemented the font. At the very least a link to the page would help.

Comment: Sorry. Edited it. Now it's there

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome on W7

Comment: You might have to bump the font-size up a bit.

Comment: Guess it's an issue with just my Chrome. Would still love to know what might cause it. Atleast I know I can safely keep working

Comment: It probably is due to anti-aliasing, which is implemented differently on Windows, Linux and OS X, as well as differences between browsers. In Chrome you can try using `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` to change how the font is rendered (I see you have subpixel-antialiasing on in your screenshot).

Comment: using -webkit-font-smoothing did not work. That's what I tried before. Switching it to 1.01em was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome on Windows always had antialiasing issues.

Try `font-size: 1.01em` instead of 1em or play with the pixel values until you find something robust.

**Example with 1.01em font-size:**
[image]